# Why does .text() return an unformated string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this text that I get from a div using the .text() function in jQuery.

```
def fibonacci(max_value):

   f_list = []

   i = 0

   while i < max_value :

       if i == 0 or i == 1 :

           f_list.append(1)

           i += 1

           continue

       else:

           f_list.append(f_list[-2] + f_list[-1])

       i += 1

   return f_list

print(fibonacci(10))
```

Why does it show like this in console log:

```
def fibonacci(max_value):
f_list = []   i = 0     while i < max_value :     if i == 0 or i == 1 :     f_list.append(1)     i += 1    continue     else:    f_list.append(f_list[-2] + f_list[-1])   i += 1    return 
f_list print(fibonacci(10))
```

How can I get it to show as it should?

Comment: Show us your markup.Chances are, your text is being broken into multiple lines using `<br>` tag, which will be stripped away by jQuery's `text`, so you lose all the line breaks.

Comment: The code is Python which is only text and doesn't really mater for this question. It seems that there's another div after the first line so it's like this:
def fibonacci(max_value):
<div></div> 
   f_list = []
Any help on how to remove the extra div?

Comment: If the code is python, that would be a good tag to use for your question.

Comment: The code doesn't matter as it's only text inside a div and is not relevant for the question.

Comment: @slam In case Terry wasn't clear: you need to post the HTML. See [mre] for reference.

Comment: Use `html()` instead of `text()`

Comment: LOL you got me, I read all the code from the code block which was actually "just text inside a div" ...

Comment: Your html contains WHITE SPACE, like a newline character. That's not shown in browser, but will be used, when shown in console.